# Specifying default value for a field for table creation in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, timestamp, default-value

Following is my table design:

```
CREATE TABLE "x"."y"(
    "z" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "a" Timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT z + 18 months,
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
;
```

How do I specify the default value of 'a'?

Can I specify this at the time of the table creation?

Comment: I've reverted your edit to the question, because it is effectively a completely new question, and invalidates the existing, accepted answer, which would be very confusing for future readers. It is perfectly fine to create a new question as a follow-up, linking back to this one to explain the connection.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for that. It would be helpful if you had asked me to put a new question as my old edits are now lost.

Comment: Don't panic, they're not lost, the revision history is available if you click the "edited 5 mins ago" label. That should take you to [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30621482/revisions) where you can see the reverted version. You can then get [the raw source of that revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/060f81bb-900f-4d42-82dc-cc552a43d180/view-source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As postgresql documentation states

> The DEFAULT clause assigns a default data value for the column whose column definition it appears within. The value is any variable-free expression (**subqueries and cross-references to other columns in the current table are not allowed**). The data type of the default expression must match the data type of the column.

It's better to use e.g. rules (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/rules-update.html)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please let me know how I specify 18 months.