# Specifying a triger to update timestamp field

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, updates, ddl

This is a follow up question on :
[old example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621482/specifying-default-value-for-a-field-for-table-creation-in-postgresql/30621626#30621626).

```
CREATE TABLE "x"."y"(
    "z" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "a" Timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT z + 18 months,
);
```

I wish to specify a trigger where a is updated as soon as z is updated.
Something on the lines of

```
CREATE TRIGGER a_update
    AFTER UPDATE on z
    on x.y
    NEW.a = NEW.z + interval '18 months'
```

Could you please help me with the syntax?

Comment: If `a` should always be 18 months after `z`, why not just use a view instead?

Comment: Thanks. I am not aware of  views. Will study and edit my question.

Comment: See my answer from some details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `a` in your scenario should **always** be 18 months after `z` there's no point in actually storing it anywhere. It would be much easier to just have it as a calculated column in a view:

```
CREATE VIEW y_view AS 
SELECT z, z + INTERVAL '18 MONTH' AS a 
FROM   y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Triggers in PostgreSQL are implemented by first creating a function, and then attaching that function to the appropriate table, as [documented in the Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/trigger-definition.html).

The [manual page for `CREATE TRIGGER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html) has this example, which should be easy to adapt to your actual names:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_update
    BEFORE UPDATE ON accounts
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.balance IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.balance)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_account_update();
```

For the definition of the actual trigger function, you just need to fill out the body of this; the `OLD` and `NEW` aliases represent the old and new values of the whole row:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_trigger() RETURNS trigger
    AS $$
        NEW.foo := OLD.foo + 1;
        RETURN NEW;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

There are more notes and examples [on this manual page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html).